# I can't change tooltip bootstrap position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't change tooltip bootstrap position with jQuery. 
Example on http://jsfiddle.net/2cast8g8/

If I enter a bigger value in text1 my function ck() need to change the position of tooltip.

Also it is possible to change the color of tooltip in red with jQuery?

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="title" value=""  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"title="this need to be less">
<input type="text" id="text2" name="title" value=""  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"title="bigger ">
```

```
$('#text1').change(function () {
    ck()
});
$('#text2').change(function () {
    ck()
});

function ck() {
    text1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    text2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    if (Number(text1) > Number(text2)) {
        $("#text2").attr("data-original-title", "This value need to be bigger than ");
        $("#text1").attr("data-placement", "top");
        $(function () {
            $('#text2').tooltip('hide').tooltip('show');
        });
    } else {
        $("#text2").attr("data-original-title", "bigger");
    }
}
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').tooltip({
    placement: function(tip, element) { 
        //code to calculate the position here, return values: "left", "right", "top", "bottom"
    },
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
});
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, he wants to modify/customize the exact position of the tooltip (move it more to the left or to the right).  The above function can only return one of the built-in positions.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap tooltip plugin has a 'placement' option which controls the general position (top,bottom,left,right) of the tooltip, but it calculates the exact position in this function:

```
Tooltip.prototype.getCalculatedOffset = function (placement, pos, actualWidth, actualHeight) {
return placement == 'bottom' ? { top: pos.top + pos.height,   left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2 } :
       placement == 'top'    ? { top: pos.top - actualHeight, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2 } :
       placement == 'left'   ? { top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left - actualWidth } :
    /* placement == 'right' */ { top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left + pos.width }
 }
```

You could override this function to provide your own logic (perhaps by adding a 'custom' placement type.  Note that the plugin applies the position type as a class to the element in addition to setting the css position properties.  These classes are removed in the `setContent` function so you'd have to adjust that function to remove your new custom placement type class.  It's likely there are other issues/considerations you'd have to account for as well - this wouldn't be a simple option. But it would be an interesting project and might even be worthy of a pull request :)

An alternative would be to simply move/override the position after the bootstrap plugin was done.  There is a 'shown' event made available, but it is only triggered after the css transitions have been applied, so it may not suitable.

An example might be something like this (untested code):

```
$('#text2').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
  var left = $(this).css('left');
  $(this).css({
     left: left + 50
   });
})
```

You might want to look at the jQueryUI tooltip widget - it has more features for positioning the tooltip (including adding custom offsets). http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position

Comment: .tooltip.top .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;} I want to use this css.  $("#text1").attr("data-placement", "top"); If is not ok the data fom textbox, I switch the tooltip from bottom to top, to make the tooltip red.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the question is here. You should be able to put the color change logic in the shown event.

Comment: I want to change the position because I can't change the color in red if a user make something wrong. So I add to css: .tooltip.top .tooltip-inner {background-color: #f00;} When is not wrong the data from the user I keep to bottom the tooltip. When is wrong I want to use the the built-in positions top because in my css is red. I can't change with jquery the tooltip color in red.